# Laravel Error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, undefined-function, artisan-serve

I have defined a debug_to_console function in the public/index.php file in the global namespace

I am trying to access this function inside the App\Providers\AppServiceProvider class in the boot() method

When I try to start my Laravel application using "php artisan serve" command I get the following error

Call to undefined function debug_to_console()

at app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:22
18▕      * Bootstrap any application services.
19▕      */
20▕     public function boot(): void
21▕     {
➜  22▕         \debug_to_console("Foo");
23▕     }
24▕
25▕ }

1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::boot()

2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:41
Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()

**When I remove the function call and start the app then rewrite the function call while the server is working it works fine which means if the server was running the code works with the function call**

Also when I call the function from a controller method it works

What is the cause of this error and how can I avoid it ?

Comment: `public/index.php` is only loaded on incoming *web* requests; `php artisan serve` doesn't include it, so any functions defined there will not be available. (It would also be unavailable in cron, queue jobs, etc.) See the duplicate thread for the correct way to handle these sorts of add-on functions.

Comment: If you've defined the debug_to_console function in the global namespace in the public/index.php file, it might not be immediately available in the context of your AppServiceProvider class, which is part of the Laravel application structure. Laravel loads its core and application files in a specific order, and the public/index.php file is usually loaded after the service providers are booted. you can put your function in helper and include the helpers.php file in the composer.json